# Best way to connect a MacBook Pro to a projector

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, video-adapter, projector

I recently purchased this [projector](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG0QFjAA&url=http://www.benq.com/product/projector/ms513&ei=HeqpT5PRN6mH0AWm-5mbBA&usg=AFQjCNGfn7DrXZKf61rQhGkmeZ111DJh6w) that has HDMI, VGA, and S-video inputs. Also, I have one of the first versions of the MacBook Pro, from around 2007/8. Currently I have connected both devices vía VGA using the Apple DVI to VGA adapter. The thing is that even at 1440x900, I have trouble making out text.

This is an 1152x870 picture taken with iPhone:
[image]

I was wondering if one of the Apple DVI to HDMI adapters will help to get a better image? Would a clone be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI will provide a higher resolution. You don't need to use any sort of special 'Mac' or Apple produced cable for this -  DVI to HDMI cables are widely available and affordable from the Internet retailer of your choice. Just hook it up and you're good to go.

(N.B. while HDMI is capable of carrying Audio as well as Video, the DVI output on your MBP does not output sound. If you'd like to connect your MacBook to the projector or some other external audio device, you'll need a separate, but again, quite standard, audio cable to do so.)

Comment: hi there. so should it be the same (in video terms) to connect dvi to hdmi than megaspecialMacbookPlug to hdmi??

Comment: Assuming you have one of the MBP's that has a real, standard, DVI port, yes. I don't remember exactly when Apple switched to Mini-DVI/DisplayPort/Thunderbolt (that video out port has been iterated on more than any other physical design aspect of the machines by a mile), but while some of those plug types are *uncommon*, none of them are sufficiently nonstandard that you'd be locked in to buying it from Apple.

Comment: ok, thanks. just one more thing. when you say "provide a higher resolution"; did you mean higher pixel resolution or higher image quality. (remember my problem is I can't read properly the letters, it doesn't really matter wich resolution i use; of corse 800x600 lets me read, but the viewport it's just too small...)

Answer (score 0):

The projector's specs indicate a native resolution of 800x600 pixels; it probably will accept a higher input resolution and is simply downscaling, which would result in blurry text.  Otherwise I'd agree on using DVI to HDMI, even if the output is only 800.